# How does Stack Overflow persist the granular edits to the posts?

Tags: discussion, markdown, javascript

When you view a post's edits, it shows a very granular level of change monitoring (down to the character).  My question is, **is this done client-side as part of the [WMD](http://code.google.com/p/wmd/) editor JavaScript code, or is it done using a server-side text comparison**?  I would like to do something similar, and I can see the advantages and disadvantages to either approach.  The one on Stack Overflow seems to work very well, though.

I saw a couple of close votes, so let me rephrase this to be more "on topic".

I want to replicate the functionality that is demonstrated by Stack Overflow's granular recording of post edits.  What are the pros and cons of implementing this type of functionality client-side with the WMD editor's JavaScript code or server-side with a text comparison?

Comment: Are you talking about the actual look that SO uses (with strikes, etc), or how it is done programmically (just finding the changes)?

Comment: it's all in the javascript

Comment: The actual what?  If you see a post that has been edited, then you can view the edits.  It shows where text was added, where text was removed, etc.

Comment: just finding the changes

Comment: Are events raised for each keydown to save the key strokes?  Or is a comparison of the text done after the fact?

Comment: I'd guess that the changes in the edit are the result of a diff done on the content rather than keeping track of what the user actually entered when editing the post. That said, I have basically no authority on the matter.

Comment: It's basically a simple text diff. Not sure what exactly SO is using, but it's quite a commonly used utility. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PostHistory` table on [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com) reveals this if you dig in far enough.

Posts are broken down into 3 components: title, body, and tags. This is done to improve concurrency (there are only collisions when multiple users edit the *same* component) and to promote storage conservation (if a question is retagged, there's no need to store a new copy of the body).

For each revision, the *changed* components are each stored in a `PostHistory` row that contains the *entire* contents of the field. For completeness: the `Posts` table row always contains the *current* state of the post -- the only difference is that the body is in a 'cooked' state (i.e., HTML ready for page output), whereas the `PostHistory` row contains the original Markdown.

When an edit history is displayed, each field's contents from the previous applicable revision are diff'd server-side. Treatment of the tags field may be different than for title and body, as it's a much simpler field to process. I'm not sure of the method by which they do the text diffs; it's probably an open-source-based implementation of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly how it's done on here, but the accepted answer on this question offers a C# solution:
[How to find difference between two strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208094/how-to-find-difference-between-two-strings)